# visual code not opening after install

Tags: bash, text-editor

I felt I followed the instructions for visual code.  When I type

```
code .
```

into my command line I get a motion like the editor will open then nothing happens.  I opened up my bash profile and this is what was in it.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


source ~/.bashrcfunction code () { VSCODE_CWD="/Users/stevenkauyedauty/projects/node/unitTestingNode" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args ; }
function code () { VSCODE_CWD="/Users/stevenkauyedauty/projects" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args ; }
```

Not sure what to do to fix this solution, but any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
source ~/.bashrcfunction code () { VSCODE_CWD="/Users/stevenkauyedauty/projects/node/unitTestingNode" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args ; }
```

is probably the product of a copy-paste mistake that happened while following [the Mac OS X installation instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup#_mac-os-x) for Visual Studio Code. Simply remove it. The line you already have after it

```
function code () { VSCODE_CWD="/Users/stevenkauyedauty/projects" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args ; }
```

should suffice.